# WPF List of BaseClass Items and their visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a following problem

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
 public int Field{get;set;}
}

public class ChildrenClass1 : ParentClass
{
public int Field2{get;set;}
}
public class ChildrenClass2 : ParentClass
{
public int Field3{get;set;}
}
```

No I have a list of ParentClass.

```
List<ParentClass> Parents = new List<ParentClass>();
```

I bind it to Listbox like this.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Parents}"/>
```

And now if it is of type ChildrenClass1 I want to show Field2 and if it is ChildrenClass2 I want to show Field3 in ListBox ItemTemplate.

The first solutions that came to my head is to do something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Parents}"/>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Converter = {StaticResource Converter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And converter should check for the type of item and return Field2 if it is ChildrenClass1 and so on.

But I think it is workaround rather than solution. Is there anything that can check types in xaml or something like this? How do you solve this problem ?

EDIT: What about situation if I want to change dramatically DataTemplate not only one field? The above workaround will be useless. Workaround for this problem is to make 2 ListBoxes with different DataTemplate and set the visibility with converter checking actual typeof item. But it will generate many binding errors and generate 2 listboxes instead of one which slows our application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two DataTemplate for each type, and WPF play it all magic.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:ChildrenClass1}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Field2}"/>
</DataTemplate>

 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:ChildrenClass2}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Field3}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```